# How to add one month in current month?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose the current month is "Oct". I want that it will add one month in current month i.e it will show "Nov". For this my code is written below but it gives exception that Input string was not in a correct format.

So please correct the code?

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedIndex ) <= Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString()))
            {
                TotalBalanceUptoSelectedPreviousMonth();
            }
```

Comment: Try writing `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString()` to the debug console - is it what you expect?

Comment: +1 on comment for promoting self-discovery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should probably work:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedIndex ) 
    <= Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("M")))

    TotalBalanceUptoSelectedPreviousMonth();
```

However, it looks simpler like this:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedIndex) <= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month)
    Total...();
```

Comment: If it is December then DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month returns 1 as the month has been changed to January whereas DateTime.Now.Month +1 returns 13.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't think about that. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go out on a limb and say that this is what you're looking for:

```
if(ddlMonth.SelectedIndex <= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month)
{
    TotalBalanceUptoSelectedPreviousMonth();
}
```

Instead of getting the date as a string and converting it, why not use the `Month` property of the DateTime struct (which is already an integer)?

(Oh...and SelectedIndex is already an integer as well, no need for the call to Convert)

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString())
```

probably gives the exception since DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString() value is not castable to Int32.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month`.
Also you do not need to use the ToString method wrapped in a Convert.ToInt32 method as this is already an integer.